# How to merge array of objects by its key in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, filtering

I have a array of objects like these:

```json
[
  {
    user: {
      key1: ['1', '2', '3'],
    },
  },
  {
    user: {
      key2: ['3', '4', '5'],
    },
  },
  {
    user2: {
      key1: ['1', '2', '3'],
    },
  },
  {
    user2: {
      key2: ['3', '4', '5'],
    },
  },
....
];
```

And I need to filter those by its keys and expecting an output like these

```json
[
    {
        user: {
            key1: ['1', '2', '3'],
            key2: ['3', '4', '5'],
        },
    },
    {
        user2: {
            key1: ['1', '2', '3'],
            key2: ['3', '4', '5'],
            ....
        }
    }
]
```

Here user, user2 can be any key(userName) also key1, key 2 etc... may be any key(userActivity) with an array of string.

Here is the type of object:

```
[key: string]: {
    [key: string]: string[];
  };
}[];
```

Which will be the best way to filter this any help would be appreciated

Comment: do every object in the original array have only one key like `user`,`user2`or there could be more than one?

Comment: yes its only contain only key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `reduce()` method:

- Iterate over each item from the `data` array
- Check if the `key` from item already exists in final result
- If it exists, concatenate current value and new value
- If it does not exist, initialize new value

```js
const data = [
 { user: { key1: ['1', '2', '3'] } },
 { user: { key2: ['3', '4', '5'] } },
 { user2: { key1: ['1', '2', '3'] } },
 { user2: { key2: ['3', '4', '5'] } }
];

const result = data.reduce((accumulator, currentValue)=>{
  const currentKey = Object.keys(currentValue)[0];
  
  if(Object.keys(accumulator).includes(currentKey)) {
     accumulator[currentKey] = {...accumulator[currentKey], ...currentValue[currentKey]};
  } else {
     accumulator[currentKey] = currentValue[currentKey];
  }
  
  return accumulator;
},{})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

an idea with array.reduce

```js
var data = [{
    user: {
      key1: ['1', '2', '3'],
    },
  },
  {
    user: {
      key2: ['3', '4', '5'],
    },
  },
  {
    user2: {
      key1: ['1', '2', '3'],
    },
  },
  {
    user2: {
      key2: ['3', '4', '5'],
    },
  }
];

let result = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  Object.keys(curr).forEach(key => {
    let found = acc.find(elem => elem[key]);
    if (found) {
      found[key] = {...found[key], ...curr[key]}
    } else {
      acc.push(curr);
    }
  });
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps

```js
const initial = [
  {
    user: {
      key1: ['1', '2', '3'],
    },
  },
  {
    user: {
      key2: ['3', '4', '5'],
    },
  },
  {
    user2: {
      key1: ['1', '2', '3'],
    },
  },
  {
    user2: {
      key2: ['3', '4', '5'],
    },
  },
];

let result = initial.reduce((acc, curr)=>{
    if(Object.keys(curr)[0]) {
        const key =Object.keys(curr)[0]
        const values = curr[key]
        acc = {
            ...acc,
            [key]: {
                ...acc[key],
                ...values
            }
        }
        return acc
    }
},[])
```